# OPC UA Connection to IP Address (when hostname couldn't be resolved)

Tags: opc-ua, milo

I'm trying to connect to OPC UA Server which is located over local intranet, though the OPC Server is exposing the Computer Name as a hostname when trying to connect through the given IP address and eventually error out as hostname can't be resolved.

While on the other side, Prosys OPC UA Client can successfully connect to it. I'm currently using Eclipse Milo, but would like to understand how other clients connect to IP Address rather than the hostname while I couldn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asked and answered here: [Java OPC-UA Client Eclipse Milo endpoint URL changes to localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40554198/java-opc-ua-client-eclipse-milo-endpoint-url-changes-to-localhost)

Instead of using the sample code in that post there is now a helper method in `EndpointUtil.updateUrl` that you can use.